# Chrome search field adds an small x... What is the jQuery event for when that is clicked?

Tags: jquery, search, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you detect the clearing of a “search” HTML5 input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977023/how-do-you-detect-the-clearing-of-a-search-html5-input)

You know in Google Chrome when you have a text field as type="search" that it adds a magnifying glass and a small "x" to the right?

How do I detect if that is clicked?

I tried to bind .click .mousedown .clear and more but nothing works.

I am trying to switch to a different view when the field is cleared.

I got it working when you backspace to empty but it doesn't work when you click the X.

Thanks!

Comment: if you could post the code that would be of much help to understand the problem better...

Comment: This questin has already ben asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977023/how-do-you-detect-the-clearing-of-a-search-html5-input