# Using jquery event on close button in search box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The question is whether I can call a function on event of clicking close button in search box.
What I'm using is `<input type='search'>`

While typing, close button appears clicking on which I want to call a particular function. Is it possible? I tried to Google it but couldn't get much out of it. Can anyone help?

Comment: it is not clear what do you want to achieve. Which part is already done? give the fiddle please

Comment: I do not know whether this thing is possible or not, so a question. When you have `<input type='search'>` in your code, it shows clear button at the end of you search field when you type. If you click on that clear button, that clears all characters from search box. I want to trigger an event on that click, to close my another div.

Comment: Yes it is possible... you might want to look at the jQuery `.on()` function.

Comment: I'm well aware about the jQuery, but that clear button is integrated in HTML5 search box, I do not on which part I should use `.on` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.on('search', function() { ... })` to handle this event.   Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/7EynL/

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977023/how-do-you-detect-the-clearing-of-a-search-html5-input) for additional details.

Answer (score 2):

Use '[search](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdvxmhr.php)' event

```
$('input[type="search"]').on('search', function(event) {
});
```