# How do you detect the clearing of a type “search” HTML5 input in ASP.NET using TextBoxFor?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, razor, jquery-events

I saw similar solutions on detecting and assigning actions when 'X' button pressed on type="search" textfield [action upon pressing X button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977023/how-do-you-detect-the-clearing-of-a-search-html5-input).
I want to do using  `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchTerm, new { id = "search-box", type = "search"}`. However it cannot fire the event specifically on clearance button 'X' click.

So far I have managed to register all events:

```
$('#search-box').on('click', function (e) {
    alert(e);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(e.target);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your requirement is `'X'` button in `@Html.TextBoxfor` and whenever clicks on `'X'` the text box become empty. Right ?

Comment: @SunilKumar It clears the text from textBox upon pressing 'X' without having any code, but my requirement is to redirect to home page when the user clicks 'X' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried following code:

`HTML:`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="clearable" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="" />
```

`JQuery:`

```
function tog(v){return v?'addClass':'removeClass';} 
$(document).on('input', '.clearable', function(){
    $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
}).on('mousemove', '.x', function( e ){
    $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth-18 < e.clientX-this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
}).on('touchstart click', '.onX', function( ev ){
    ev.preventDefault();
    alert('33');// put window.location('url goes here');
    $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('').change();
});
```

`CSS:`

```
.clearable{
  background: #fff url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJotv.gif) no-repeat right -10px center;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 3px 18px 3px 4px;     /* Use the same right padding (18) in jQ! */
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
.clearable.x  { background-position: right 5px center; } /* (jQ) Show icon */
.clearable.onX{ cursor: pointer; }              /* (jQ) hover cursor style */
.clearable::-ms-clear {display: none; width:0; height:0;} /* Remove IE default X */
```

Fiddle is here : [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/dzz7btsf/)

Hope it helps you .. :)

Happy Coding..