# Angular event binding for input (type="search") cross icon?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to bind an event with Angular 2 (4, 5, 6, 7) for the cross icon of an `<input type="search">`? Which event gets triggered?

Looking for a solution like (other than (search) because it does not work in IE):

```
<input type="search" (click)="search()">
```

Additional question: What's the official name of this cross icon? Kinda hard googling/duckduckgoing for a solution when not knowing the right terms?

Duplicate Question: [How do you detect the clearing of a "search" HTML5 input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977023/how-do-you-detect-the-clearing-of-a-search-html5-input)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
 <input type="search" (search)="search()">
```

Comment: That should also fire the `search` event, the value will then be empty.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977023/how-do-you-detect-the-clearing-of-a-search-html5-input

Comment: You're welcome. As mentioned in the linked answer, IE11 doesn't fire `search`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is correct. At the time of writing, this also applies to Firefox (Gecko).

Answer (score 10):

**There are multiple ways of binding the search event with component**

**1) Using change event**

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" (change)="onSearchCustomer($event)">
// This event get fired when you type something and hit enter, but if you 
// again hit enter without adding a new input it won't get fired. 
//(i.e It fires only when the content changes and mean while enter is pressed)
```

**2) Using search event**

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" (search)="onSearchCustomer($event)">
// This event is fired whenever enter is pressed.(i.e without caring about the change of content)
```

**3) Using keyup event**

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" (keyup)="onSearchCustomer($event)">
// This event is fired on every key press
```

**4) Using keyup.enter event**

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" (keyup.enter)="onSearchCustomer($event)">
// This event is similar to search event which only fires when enter is pressed
```

Now in your Component file

```
onSearchCustomer(event: any) {
   console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

Hope this will help you or somebody else!

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search for text" #searchInput (keyup)="search(searchInput.value)" (search)="search()">
```