# Why isn't my element being emptied as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sure this is very simple but I'm stuck.

I have an input, when a value is entered I would like to append this value to a `<span>` element. Once the value is deleted from the input, I would like to also remove it from the `<span>` element.

The issue i'm having is that the input value is removed, but the html 'Name' remains.

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/age3nyph/1/).

```
<input type="search" id="searchName" type="text">
<div id="searchFilter">
  <p><span id="filterName"></span></p>
</div>

$('#searchName').keyup(function() {
  if ($('#searchName').length > 0) {
    $("#filterName").text('Name: ' + $('#searchName').val());
  } else {
    $("#filterName").empty();
  }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like `.empty()` is ever getting called. You never go into that else statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluate the length of the `val()`, not the element itself:

```
$('#searchName').keyup(function() {
  if ($('#searchName').val().length > 0) {
    $("#filterName").text('Name: ' + $('#searchName').val());
  } else {
    $("#filterName").empty();
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/age3nyph/3/)

Comment: Keep in mind this doesn't work if the element is cleared by clicking the `x`

Comment: Thanks @blackandorangecat - probably a separate question but what if the element is cleared by clicking the x ?

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek   `$('#searchName').on('search', function () {
    $("#filterName").empty();
});`

Comment: Add that (new listener) above/below the answer above.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977023/how-do-you-detect-the-clearing-of-a-search-html5-input

Answer (score 0):

With a few modif. it's ok :-)

```js
$('#searchName').on("keyup",function() {
  if ($('#searchName').val() != "") {
    $("#filterName").text('Name: ' + $('#searchName').val());
  } else {
    $("#filterName").text("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="searchName" type="text">
<div id="searchFilter">
  <p><span id="filterName"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition in the if to:

```
$('#searchName').val().length > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the keyup to the body element, not the input box itself then it will register the event and work -

```
$('body').keyup(function() {
  if($('#searchName').length > 0) {
    $("#filterName").text('Name: ' + $('#searchName').val());
  } else {
    $("#filterName").empty();
  }
});
```

Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/age3nyph/4/

Answer (score 0):

I would handle the 'search' and 'keyup' events to account for users clicking the 'x' and users typing in the field. See [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jwkxkp13/1/)

```
$('#searchName').on('keyup', function() {
updateFilter(this);
});

$('#searchName').on('search', function(){
updateFilter(this);
});

function updateFilter(element){
if ($(element).val().length > 0) {
    $("#filterName").text('Name: ' + $(element).val());
 } else {
$("#filterName").empty();
 }
};
```

Edit: Updated link to point at JSFiddle setup to use JQuery. Original link excluded that update.