# Is there a way to detect keypress/enter in search event?

Tags: javascript, html, search, dom-events

I am looking for a way to differentiate between pressing Enter in a `input[type="search"]` event (search-event), and clearing the query by clicking X.

I have tried looking for variables in `e` and `e.target`

The only thing I can think of is:

```js
search.addEventListener("search", (e) => {
 e.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
   if (event.key === "Enter") {
     ....
   }
 });

});
```

But I don't like this at all, and there is no way to specifically detect the clicking X.
Normally I use handler functions, so the code readability will suffer from this event nesting I think.

Is there a built in way or better way to achieve this? All help & thoughts are welcome!

Comment: `search` is a non-standard event, so you are probably better looking for key events on the input element. From there you can easily check if it was X or any other key and react accordingly.

Comment: be careful when adding events inside of events, because every time you trigger the search event you are adding a keypress event

Comment: @Gavin I have made edits to my post now, because the phrasing of pressing X was wrong. In the search element you can press Enter, and click X. That's what's throwing me off I think.

Comment: @DivineSoul yes, thank you for explaining this. I didn't specifically know why, but I had a red hot feeling that I didn't like the event nesting at all.

Comment: Just listen for `keyup`/`change` instead. `search` is strange to use.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, there is no way to differentiate between these two, unless you use specific function with onClick event handler.
This can also help.
[How do you detect the clearing of a "search" HTML5 input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977023/how-do-you-detect-the-clearing-of-a-search-html5-input)