# Attach event to clear icon in IE10 textbox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, textbox, internet-explorer-10

In IE10 a small X icon appears in the textbox to clear the input text. How can an event be attached to that action (=clicking on that X and clearing the input)?

Comment: Can you show us some code? What event do you want to be attached to it? Not having IE10, I'm not sure, but does that element have any markup associated with it, or is it part of the native browser chrome?

Comment: @nickcoxdotme It's native to IE 10. You can download it for free, you know: http://www.modern.ie/virtualization-tools

Comment: doesn't have any markup. it comes built in with text boxes in IE10. Code: just display some text.

Comment: @ABC Have you tried `onchange`?

Comment: @Teemu, no, let me try it.

Answer (score 13):

It seems there's not an exact event for this (`onchange` is not suitable). However, you can use `oninput` and check, if the value of the `input` is empty:

```
document.getElementById('input_ID').addEventListener('input', function () {
    if (this.value === '') {
        alert('No value');
    }
}, false);
```

This event is triggered also, if user clears the `input` with <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> or <kbd>DELETE</kbd>, or cuts the content to the clipboard. `oninput` works at least in Chrome, FF, IE10 and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

pl refer :[Event fired when clearing text input on IE10 with clear icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21145761/799593)