# Handle IE 9 & 10's clear button with Knockout binding

Tags: internet-explorer, input, knockout.js

I have an input text box bound to a [knockout js](http://www.knockoutjs.com) observable.

```
<input id="searchTextBox" class="searchTextBox" type="text" maxlength="25"
       title="Search" placeholder="Search"
       data-bind="value: GridVm.FilterText,
       valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
       disable: GridVm.Data().length == 0" />
```

The problem is that the FilterText observable doesn't update when the user clicks the x in IE.

I've found that I can [remove the x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481577/how-can-i-disable-the-clear-button-that-ie10-inserts-into-textboxes) (see the screen shot in the linked question), but that's a last resort (I like the feature). [This forum says there is no event fired when the x is clicked](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/autocomplete/ie-10-clear-x-not-clearing-selected-value.aspx).

Is there an event that I can use to force a Knockout observable update or a good way to do this in Knockout?

Comment: try the click binding

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just change

```
valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'
```

to

```
valueUpdate: 'input'
```

it hooks that event to trigger the value update. It's better overall because it also handles clipboard-based actions and text drag-drop actions.

Comment: Nice find! This worked for me too. I'm changing to yours as the answer and updating my Fiddle.

Comment: Yes perfect solution.

Comment: I found that changing the data-bind from value to textInput resolved the issue nicely.  In order to stop it updating after every key I made it a rate limiting observable: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html for details.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out using the [input event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700466/attach-event-to-clear-icon-in-ie10-textbox) and [Knockout's event binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html). Here is [my JsFiddle showing the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/logankd/LH7RT/) with the code below.

```
<input type="search" id="input1" data-bind="value: textForBox, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
  event: { input: cleared }" />
var vm = {
    textForBox: ko.observable(),
    cleared: function (data, event) {
        if (event.currentTarget.value === '') {
           this.textForBox('');
        }
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```