# How to capture event when clicking on browser (HTA) textbox clear x

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have an HTA with a textbox.  I am using Windows 10.  The HTA (IE) automatically puts an "x" to the right of the textbox when it is active.  What is the event to capture clicking on that x to clear the textbox?  I tried onchange, onclick but onclick unfortunately has the undesired effect of any click on the textbox.  I also tried onclear but that does nothing.  onreset also does nothing.

Comment: Depends on what kind of control that "x" is.

Comment: It's unclear. What did you mean by "x" describe more your issue by adding your code while editing it !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14700466/1169519

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach event to clear icon in IE10 textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700466/attach-event-to-clear-icon-in-ie10-textbox)