# Detect texbox clear-event in IE. How do I clear the input type="text" (textbox) in IE (Internet Explorer) when IE-specific clear-box is clicked?

Tags: javascript, textbox

In Internet Explorer, there is a little x-like button is shown, when you start typing in the textbox. How do I detect the event when this icon is clicked on? Is there an event-type?

```
<input type="text" value ="" id ="qsearch" name="qsearch"
    onBlur="qsearchLookup(this.value);" OnClick="qsearchLookup(this.value);"
    onkeyup="qsearchLookup(this.value)"  size="26">

function qsearchLookup(searchVal){
    document.getElementById("qsearch").value="";
}
```

[image]

Comment: I found this solution really helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14498921/1895428

Comment: post it as the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not know about special event for this small x-like button, and I don't think that it exists, but you can use [input](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/forms.html#event-input-input) event (`oninput="qsearchLookup(this.value)"` in your case) to catch this change.

Comment: I added image; seems like event is not catching it

Comment: It works in IE10, and I thought that this (x) button exists only in IE10. I don't think that IE has special DOM element for this button or event, but if you want you can hide it with special css: `::-ms-clear { display: none; }`

Answer (score 8):

Am not sure, if still someone is looking for a solution. Unfortunately there is no event handler available for the ***clear(X) icon***, however below code snippet/tricks worked for me. CSS to complete hide the ***clear(X) icon*** and if you don't want to hide the ***clear(X) icon*** but need to handle then JS code snippet would help.Verified in IE 8,9,10,11 and it works fine

***CSS trick:***

`#textFieldId::-ms-clear {display: none;}` -- For a particular text field

or

`input[type=text]::-ms-clear { display: none; }` -- for all text fields in scope

***OR***

***JavaScript trick (to reset the text field value to empty/blank and fire the html event KeyUp. Accordingly you can change per your need)***

```
$('#textFieldId').bind("mouseup", function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        var oldValue = $input.val();
        if (oldValue == "") {
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            var newValue = $input.val();
            if (newValue == "") {
                $input.trigger("keyup");
            }
        }, 1);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. This JS was the only thing I could get working in Edge (IE11 was already working for me via another event somehow). Would never have thought of the Timeout part myself (ridiculous this is seemingly required).

Answer (score 0):

This worked pretty well for me :)

```
$input.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($input.value === '') do_stuff();
    }, 1)
});
```

`$input` being a reference to the input element.

Answer (score -1):

```
input.on('input propertychange',function(e){})
```

this works for ie10 (input) and ie8 (propertychange) but not for ie9

i actually fixed it for ie9 with the mousedown event, not pretty ,but that and mouseup are the only events that fire on it