# Data-bind on Select element not refreshing in certain cases

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a Select element that I'm creating using jQueryUI and then binding with knockout. I also have a text Input element that I'm using to filter (created the same way as the Select). In most cases the filtering works fine but sometimes if there's a value in the textbox and I select it with the mouse and then hit the Delete key my event fires, the data gets changed but the UI doesn't refresh.

Here's the code for my Computed property:

```
self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.valueToFilter() === "") {
        return self.items();
        //when the value is cleared this line gets
        //ran properly but the UI doesn't update
    } else {
        return jQuery.grep(self.items(), function (i) {
            return (i.indexOf(self.valueToFilter()) === 0);
        });
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Could you provide a fiddle that demonstrates it? Here is my test: http://jsfiddle.net/hd2Ea/

Comment: @Markus Thanks for the demo link. It turns out that the issue I was experiencing only seems to be happening in IE. I noticed it while looking at your fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make your code work on IE10:

```
<input type="text" id="in" data-bind="value: valueToFilter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { mouseup: function () {  valueToFilter(''); }}"/>
```

See also: [Event fired when clearing text input on IE10 with clear icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498396/event-fired-when-clearing-text-input-on-ie10-with-clear-icon)