# How to trigger event when user click on 'x' icon IE input field?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I hava a character counter for input fields its working as expected only problem i see when i use IE browser and user clear the field with 'x' icon its not setting tooltip value back to maxLength. Is there any work around how to trigger event when clear field with IE 'x'.

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
        ng-model="input.searchValue" placeholder="Enter search item"
        maxlength="256" name={{$index}}
        data-tooltip-html-unsafe="
        <div>{{256 - input.searchValue.length}} characters left</div>"
        tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'focus', false: 'never'}[ input.searchValue.length >= 0 || input.searchValue.length == null ]}}"
        tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-class = "bluefill"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You might be able to leverage the mouseup event, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498396/event-fired-when-clearing-text-input-on-ie10-with-clear-icon

Comment: Thanks for the help I used Angular ng-mouseup and it did work. Thanks again