# IE 11 textbox "X" button event

Tags: javascript, jquery

IE11, textbox "X" button is clearing the field but it is working only on onchange function. I have one save button. If the text field has empty, I want to disable that save button.

If I cleared text filed using delete key or backspace it is working. But If I click "X" button in IE11 its not working.

```js
$('.transferInput').on("change",function() {
 // alert("on change...");
  if($(".transferInput").val() == ""){ 
 $('#btnTransSave').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

I tried in click,keyup, keydown and keypress also instead of change function. But it is not working. On clicking that "X" button itself I want to disable that save button. Is there any default classname or ID is there for "X" button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event fired when clearing text input on IE10 with clear icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498396/event-fired-when-clearing-text-input-on-ie10-with-clear-icon)